# Preprocessing markup files in jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I would like to write a preprocessor that operates on a range of markup languages before they're processed into HTML by Jekyll.  Ideally the user would simply create a file called _posts/xxyyzz.md.wmd, and Jekyll would preprocess it into xxyyzz.md using a plugin I provide, and then process that into HTML in the usual way.

It looks like Jekyll's Converter framework doesn't allow that, because the `output_ext` function is only given the final extension "wmd", preventing it from returning ".md" for ".md.wmd", ".textile" for ".textile.wmd", etc.

Is there a way to implement a chain of processing steps like this?

EDIT: grammar

Comment: You question is to broad. Can you try to be more concise, show us a code example of what is supposed to be preprocessed, ...

Comment: @DavidJacquel Thank you. I've simplified this question to just one thing, and I'll post my other question separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use a [Generator plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/) that uses your wmd converter:

```
require "yourWmdConverter"

module Jekyll
  class ConvertWmd < Jekyll::Generator

    def initialize(config)
      config['convert_wmd'] ||= true
    end

    def generate(site)
      @site = site
      site.posts.docs.each { |post| convertWmd post }
    end

    private

    def convertWmd(post) 
      post.content = yourWmdConverter post.content
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Yes - this seems to work once I modify `post.content`, `post.name`, `post.slug`, and `post.ext` in place.

Comment: `site.posts.each` is deprecated in newer versions of Jekyll. Use `site.posts.docs.each` instead. See this related [issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4199).